# Publish script to deploy only particular defined tables/stored procedures/functions

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, deployment, publish

I want to create a publish script profile to deploy only particular tables and stored procedures. When this publish.xml script deploys
I want it to ensure that everything on the existing target database (tables, stored procedures, functions etc) are untouched, and only the tables sprocs and functions defined in the new project are deployed.

It looks like Microsoft have released new Advanced Publish Settings - what settings will I need to ensure nothing is changed on the target database except for deploying new tables/sprocs I have defined in my new database solution?

Note: The target database has the same name as my new Database Project, and the tables/sprocs/functions in the target database are **not** in my local new database project.
I only want to deploy changes on my local database project that are not in the target while ensuring the data/schema on the target is untouched.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Between go statement and the create statement, there are a variety of meta-data checks you could use to conditionally execute the create statement.

```
go
if object_id('SampleTable') is null
begin
    create table SampleTable
    (
        ID int identity(1,1) primary key,
        sampleField int
    )
end
GO
```

Historically, MS database projects have been less than helpful.